# OMX_ErrorUnsupportedSetting error event after assigning buffers to audio decoder component

Tags: decoding, raspberry-pi, openmax

I'm getting the OMX_ErrorUnsupportedSetting error event after providing the buffers to an audio decoder component on Raspberry Pi. I tried anything that came into my mind to change the parameters but still the callback arrives. Is there any way in the OpenMAX standard to try to investigate what parameter is causing that event?

This is what I'm doing:

1. Created the component;
2. disabled all the ports;
3. set state to idle;
4. set port format to use OMX_AUDIO_CodingAAC;
5. set port definition to use OMX_AUDIO_CodingAAC, 4 buffers of 6144 bytes each;
6. set profile to these values (not sure if needed): profileType.nSampleRate = 48000; profileType.nFrameLength = 0; profileType.nChannels = 6; profileType.nBitRate = 288000; profileType.nAudioBandWidth = 0; set OMX_PARAM_CODECCONFIGTYPE with bCodecConfigIsComplete to 1;
7. set OMX_IndexParamBrcmDecoderPassThrough to true.

After all the buffers are sent to the component, I suddenly get OMX_ErrorUnsupportedSetting event and the port is not enabled. Any idea of what I may be doing wrong or how I can inspect the parameter which is causing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been told by the manufacturer that the reason this is happening is that no audio decoder except PCM is available at the moment.